# Inline editor is no longer available: cannot exit out of edit mode with ESC or by clicking the question title

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface, editor

Like the title suggests; I have noticed today that the `ESC`ape key (on my keyboard) no longer exits a question when wanting to not save something in edit mode.

Plus, the question title that used to be clickable, no longer works that way and disappears when in edit mode, therefore I now have to physically click on "cancel" to return to the question and in some posts I am going over which can be rather long, I have to scroll down quite a bit in order to get out of that mode. Using ESC used to work and stopped working (for me) as of today.

This is for both questions and answers.

It appears that the inline editing view is no longer available, even to users with full editing privileges. What caused this regression, and can we please have it fixed?

Comment: Looks like inline editing is impossible. And that's annoying.

Comment: Ctrl+End takes me to the bottom of the page, which may or may not be helpful, depending on how many answers the question you're editing has. Might also be a Windows thing...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm on a Linux box, but thanks :)

Comment: Ctrl+End is a universal Windows keyboard shortcut, causing the vertical scroll bar to scroll all the way to the end. It's probably supported on more than a few *nix window managers, too. I don't see how that helps, though. As double-beep said, the real issue is the disappearance of the inline editor, so that's the bug that needs to be fixed. Escalated to staff review.

Comment: Reproduced Chrome 80

Comment: Inline tag editor still works.

Comment: Possibly related: When trying to edit a post in a review queue (I tried in Late Answers, but I'm assuming it's the same in other queues with similar options), clicking on "Save" after I've done my edit takes me out of the queue and to the post itself. Thus, I cannot then hit "I'm Done" and complete the review.

Comment: Cross-site: *[The 2k+ inline editor doesn't seem to work anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346435)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be fixed now. I had reversed the logic in a ternary. Thank you for finding it!

Comment: So...the inline editor was showing up when attempting to open the editor in a separate page? :-)

Comment: Right on. Thanks and you're welcome :) *Cheers*