# Action was not recorded when editing post in review queue

Tags: bug, review-queues, edits

When I made changes by editing some post in the *First Posts* review queue and clicked on "Save" button, the page was redirected to the URL where the post was. Then, I came back to check the counter, but it was not increased.

Comment: Workaround: Open the post in a different tab/window. Do the edit there. Then refresh the review. Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396588/inline-editor-is-no-longer-available-cannot-exit-out-of-edit-mode-with-esc-or-b

Comment: Here's the [report on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346472/edit-in-first-post-review-takes-you-to-the-post-not-back-to-the-review). It's a network-wide issue.

Comment: I *suspect* this is a bug introduced by [this regression](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396588/inline-editor-is-no-longer-available-cannot-exit-out-of-edit-mode-with-esc-or-b), which has now been fixed. Can you confirm? Is anyone still seeing this bug when attempting to edit in the review queues?